# How to find the size of a reg in verilog?

Tags: testing, size, verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

I was wondering if there were a way to compute the size of a reg in Verilog. I researched it quite a bit, and found $size(a), but it's only in SystemVerilog, and it won't work in my verilog program.

Does anyone know an alternative for this??

I also wanted to ask as a side note; I'm having some trouble with my test bench in the sense that when I update a value in the file, that change is not taken in consideration when I simulate. I've been told I might have been using an old test bench but the one I am continuously simulating is the only one available in this project.

EDIT:

To give you an idea of what's the problem: in my code there is a "start" signal and when it is set to 1, the operation starts. Otherwise, it stays idle. I began writing the test bench with start=0, tested it and simulated it, then edited the test bench by setting start to 1. But when I simulate it, the start signal remains 0 in the waveform. I tried to check whether I was using another test bench, but it is the only test bench I am using in this project.

Given that I was on a deadline, I worked on the code so that it would adapt to the "frozen" test bench. I am getting now all the results I want, but I wanted to test some other features of my code, so I created a new project and copy pasted the code in new files (including the same test bench). But when I ran a simulation, the waveform displayed wrong results (even though I was using the exact same code in all modules and test bench). Any idea why?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What Verilog simulator and version do you use?

Comment: Icarus Verilog (0.10.0 11/23/14) supports $size() system function. Take a look at this example: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Gph

Comment: I am using ModelSim 10.4a PE Student Edition. And I did try $size() but it didn't work with my program it just kept returning 0's.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standardised way to do this, but it requires you to use the VPI, which I don't think you get on Modelsim's student edition. In short, you have to write C code, and dynamically link it to the simulator. In the C code, you can get object properties using routines such as `vpi_get`. Useful properites might be `vpiSize`, which is what you want, `vpiLeftRange`, `vpiRightRange`, and so on.

Having said all that, Verilog is essentially a static language, and objects have to be declared with a static width using constant expressions. Having a run-time method to determine an object's size is therefore of pretty limited value (since you should already know it), and may not solve whatever problem you actually have. Your question would make more sense for VHDL (and SystemVerilog?), which are much more dynamic.

Note on Icarus: the developers have pushed lots of SystemVerilog stuff back into the main language. If you take advantge of this you may find that your code is not portable.

Second part of your question: you need to be specific on what your problem actually is.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I can get VPI, but thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Will this vpi stuff be synthesizable?